# Error HTTP GET object list

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I get an error when I try to retrieve a list of objects from a link (php server).

> Blocking of a multi-origin request (cross-origin request): the "same
>   source" policy does not allow access to the remote resource located at
>   http: //localhost/eReport/index.php. Reason:
>   "Access-control-authorization-origin" token missing in the CORS
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" CORS header.

I added a header like this tuto that is recommended on this link but I still have this error.

Can you help me please ?

**My Service page:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportService{
  private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost/report/reports.php';

  constructor(private http : Http){}
  getAll(): Observable<Report[]>{
    let report$ = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}`, { headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(mapReports);
      return report$;
  }

  private getHeaders(){
    // I included these headers because otherwise FireFox
    // will request text/html
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    return headers;
  }
  get(id: number): Observable<Report> {
    let report$ = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}/report/${id}`, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(mapReport);
      return report$;
  }
```

**My php page**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
        $tab = array(
        array('id'=> '12', 'name'=> 'test','description' => '2018-04-01','url'=>'../../../assets/img/chat1.png' ),
        array('id'=> '13', 'name'=> 'test','description' => '2018-04-01','url'=>'../../../assets/img/highcharts.png' )
    );

    echo json_encode($tab);


?>
```

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Blocking of a multi-origin request (cross-origin request): the "same source" policy does not allow access to the remote resource located at http: //localhost/eReport/index.php. Reason: "Access-control-authorization-origin" token missing in the CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" CORS header.

Comment: This is coming from your server side, you need there to allow the requests across different domains

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the quickest fix is to change your base url in the Angular app to `/report/reports.php` if the requests are going to the same server that served the app.

Your request is not working because when the client sends content of type `application/json`, the browser doesn't send the request right away. If you restart your browser then observe the network tab you will notice that instead of your `GET`, an `OPTIONS` request is first send, that includes headers similar to these:

```
Origin: yourserver
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Accept
```

In this scenario, the browser expects the server to return not just the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (which you're already doing), but all of these:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourserver (or *)
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET (or a list eg: GET, POST, OPTIONS)
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept  (the same headers from above)
```

So you need to read the request headers from the previous block, and use their values when setting the response headers. If you have the [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) method it's pretty easy. You can also get them from the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

```
// set required headers:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $_SERVER[HTTP_ORIGIN]");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: $_SERVER[HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD]");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: $_SERVER[HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS]");
```

[See this helpful article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)